# Error creating trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PILOTO_COPILOTO (
nip number, 
anos_experienciencia float)
TABLESPACE TSPROYECTOABD;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE TRIPULACION (
nip number, 
nombre varchar(20), 
apellido varchar(20), 
fecha_nac date, 
fecha_contratacion date, 
sexo char, 
idiomas varchar(50), 
nacionalidad varchar(20))
TABLESPACE TSPROYECTOABD;
```

And created the following trigger to insert a row into TRIPULACION corresponding to the new row in PILOTO_COPILOTO.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER anadir_tripulacion
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PILOTO_COPILOTO
    REFERENCING NEW AS newRow
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TRIPULACION VALUES(:newRow.NIP);
    END anadir_tripulacion;
```

I got the following errors trying to update the TRIPULACION table with the nip field of PILOTO_COPILOTO.

```
Error(7,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(7,21): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use directly `INSERT INTO VALUES(...)`, you must specify all the columns of the table.

You can precise the column in which you want insert data like this.

```
INSERT INTO TRIPULACION (nip) VALUES(:newRow.NIP);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TRIPULACION VALUES(:newRow.NIP);

>> Error(7,21): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

This is because when you omit the column list, it implies that you are inserting the complete column list, so what you are writing is really

```
INSERT INTO TRIPULACION
    (nip, nombre, apellido, fecha_nac, fecha_contratacion,
    sexo, idiomas, nacionalidad)
VALUES
    (:newRow.NIP);
```

So it is clear you have 8 columns to insert to but 1 value provided.